# Download file is getting corrupted

Tags: php, zip

I have a code function in php

What it does:

it absorbs data from a table and converts the images(saved as blob) into files and put under a subfolder named "`image`" under a folder created dynamically based on version and date

ex: `v3-20-12-2012`

Then it creates a csv file and save it in the `v3-20-12-2012` folder.

Then it creates a zip file for the folder `v3-20-12-2012`.

The problem is , the zip file getting saved in the project folder. I want it to be downloadable.

How can i achieve this.

Here's my code:

```
function create_csv($version,$ctg,$cnt,$nt,$api)
{

    $folder = $version."-".date('d-m-Y')."-".time();

    if(!file_exists('./'.$folder))
    {
        mkdir('./'.$folder);
        mkdir('./'.$folder.'/image/');
    }   

    $cnt_table = "aw_countries_".$version;
    $ctg_table = "aw_categories_".$version;
    $off_table = "aw_offers_".$version;


    $sizeof_ctg = count($ctg);
    $cond_ctg = " ( ";
    for($c = 0; $c < $sizeof_ctg ; $c++)
    {
        $cond_ctg = $cond_ctg." $ctg_table.category = '".$ctg[$c]."' ";
        if($c < intval($sizeof_ctg-1))
            $cond_ctg = $cond_ctg." OR ";
        else if($c == intval($sizeof_ctg-1))
            $cond_ctg = $cond_ctg." ) ";
    }

    $sizeof_cnt = count($cnt);
    $cond_cnt = " ( ";
    for($cn = 0; $cn < $sizeof_cnt ; $cn++)
    {
        $cond_cnt = $cond_cnt." $cnt_table.country = '".$cnt[$cn]."' ";
        if($cn < intval($sizeof_cnt-1))
            $cond_cnt = $cond_cnt." OR ";
        else if($cn == intval($sizeof_cnt-1))
            $cond_cnt = $cond_cnt." ) ";
    }

    $sizeof_nt = count($nt);
    $cond_nt = " ( ";
    for($n = 0; $n < $sizeof_nt ; $n++)
    {
        $cond_nt = $cond_nt." $off_table.network_id = '".$nt[$n]."' ";
        if($n < intval($sizeof_nt-1))
            $cond_nt = $cond_nt." OR ";
        else if($n == intval($sizeof_nt-1))
            $cond_nt = $cond_nt." ) ";
    }

    $sizeof_api = count($api);
    $cond_api = " ( ";
    for($a = 0; $a < $sizeof_api ; $a++)
    {
        $cond_api = $cond_api." $off_table.api_key = '".$api[$a]."' ";
        if($a < intval($sizeof_api-1))
            $cond_api = $cond_api." OR ";
        else if($a == intval($sizeof_api-1))
            $cond_api = $cond_api." ) ";
    }

    $output         = "";

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT $off_table.id,$off_table.name
            FROM $off_table,$cnt_table,$ctg_table
            WHERE  $off_table.id = $cnt_table.id
            AND $off_table.id = $ctg_table.id
            AND ".$cond_api."
            AND ".$cond_nt."
            AND ".$cond_cnt."
            AND ".$cond_ctg;

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $columns_total  = mysql_num_fields($result);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) 
    {
        $heading    =   mysql_field_name($result, $i);
        $output     .= '"'.$heading.'",';
    }
    $output .= '"icon"';
    $output .="\n";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) 
        {
            $output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
        }
        $sql_icon = "SELECT $off_table.icon FROM $off_table WHERE id = '".$row['id']."'";
        $result_icon = mysql_query($sql_icon);
        while($row_icon = mysql_fetch_array($result_icon)) 
        {
            $image = $row_icon["icon"];
            $id = $row["id"];
            $icon = "./$folder/image/{$id}.jpg";
            $icon_link = "$folder/image/{$id}.jpg";
            file_put_contents($icon, $image);
        }
        $output .= '"'.$icon_link.'"';
        $output .="\n";
    }
    $filename =  "myFile.csv";
    $fd = fopen ( "./$folder/$filename", "w");
    fputs($fd, $output);
    fclose($fd);

    $source = $folder;
    $destination = $folder.'.zip';

    $flag = '';

    if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
        return false;
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
        return false;
    }

    $source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));
    if($flag)
    {
        $flag = basename($source) . '/';
    }

    if (is_dir($source) === true)
    {
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $file = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($file));

            if (is_dir($file) === true)
            {
            }
            else if (is_file($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $flag.$file), file_get_contents($file));
            }
        }
    }
    else if (is_file($source) === true)
    {
        $zip->addFromString($flag.basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
    }

    $zip->close();

    if (is_dir($folder)) 
    { 
        $objects = scandir($folder); 
        foreach ($objects as $object) 
        { 
           if ($object != "." && $object != "..") 
           { 
                if (filetype($folder."/".$object) == "dir") 
                {
                    $object_inner = scandir($folder."/".$object);
                    foreach ($object_inner as $object_inner) 
                    { 
                       if ($object_inner != "." && $object_inner != "..") 
                       { 
                            unlink($folder."/".$object."/".$object_inner); 
                       } 
                    } 
                    rmdir($folder."/".$object); 
                }   
                else 
                    unlink($folder."/".$object); 
           } 
        } 
        reset($objects); 
    } 
    rmdir("./".$folder);

    /*$zipfile = $folder.'.zip';

    $file_name = basename($zipfile);

    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zipfile));

    readfile($zipfile);
    exit;*/


}




EDIT:
```

I have two instance of the file. One file gettng saved automaticaly at the project folder. The next one is getting forced to download. The one that is automatically saved has no prolem whle unzipping. But the one that is forcefully download, that having issue while unzipping.

[image: Zip Error Message]

[image: Error Message]

Comment: put an html tag <a> with href that file wont' work?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to send the actual data at the end and it would be nice to also send the Content-Length header.

Example:

```
$filename = 'something.zip';
$filepath = './path/to/files/directory/';


header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath.$filename));
ob_end_flush();
readfile($filepath.$filename);
```

And as a side note, you may want to split that function because it does more than it should. As name states, it should just `create_csv`, but is also working with DB, creating a zip, sending the response, etc.

#### Update:

After your update I looked closely to your code and you have a few issues which might result in a corrupted download:

```
$source = str_replace('\\', '\\', realpath($source));
// more code ...
$file = realpath($file);
```

Those lines will result in full paths being used in archive, which you might not want. I recommend commenting those two lines so you store relative paths inside the archive.

After you add all your files to your archive, you don't close it and because the archive will have a temporary name which is different than its final one, your code used when sending headers will result in sending garbage data.

To fix that, you should close the .zip before sending the headers:

```
// more code ... 

$zip->close();

header('Content-type: application/zip');
```

Comment: @Saswat The code does work and it was just an example. In order to leave you with something to exercise, I preferred giving you an example instead of an integration ready to be used in your script. A copy/paste solution does not encourage anyone to learn. However, if you have trouble making it to work, you can give more information about what does not work (*valuable information like actual errors/warning, not "does not work"*) and I can try to help you.

Comment: see, my edit section of the question....http://stackoverflow.com/users/1459926/alexandru-guzinschilexandru

Comment: @Saswat Comment all the headers from the end of the file so you don't download anything and access the file from your browser in order to see any warning and errors so you can debug it. Also check on your server if the files are created and if the archive is not corrupted.